# Repeating call of methods

Tags: c#, methods, dataset

I have a static class for providing a connection to a dataset.

I have chosen static, so every class can call the dataset, without initializing it every time.

So this class contains a method `public static void Init() {...}` where I fill the dataset with the table adapters.

Also, I have several methods, that query for me to separate Dataset Queries from the other code logic.

In each of these methods i have to check if the dataset is initialized already.

Here's my question: Is there a possibility to do this check, whatever function of this class is called, without explicitly implementing it in every function ?

Or is there a basic mistake in my modeling this DB stuff ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `Lazy<T>`:

```
private static Lazy<DataSet> CoreMyDataSet = new Lazy<DataSet>(() => {
  Init();

  // ... Other code if required      

  // return dataset created
  return s_MyDataSet;
});

public static DataSet MyDataSet {
  get {
    return CoreMyDataSet.Value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that is just the basic problem with static code. You never know in which state another part of your code left it... Well not **never** but you get the idea.

What does your code do when you check for initialization fails? Can you just initialize it right away or do you stop further execution?

One method would be to check for initialization in your methods of your static class and do whatever the caller would do when the check fails. But this heavily depends on your options.

Comment: Yeah, thats the way I did it so far. Atm I check in every method

My init methods only fills the datasets.